# Docker container's http response slower when not detached

Tags: http, docker

I am using Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72 on CentOS 7.2.1511.

I am going through the [docker getting started tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app). I have played around with docker a bit beyond this, but not much.

I have built the `friendlyhello` image by copy-pasting from the website. When running with

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 friendlyhello
```

I can `curl localhost:8080` and get a response in ~20ms. However, when I run

```
docker run -p 8080:80 friendlyhello
```

i.e., without being detached from the container, trying to `curl localhost:8080` takes over 50 *seconds*. This makes no sense to me.

EDIT: it seems that killing containers repeatedly may have something to do with this. Either that, or it's random whether a given container can serve quickly or not. After stopping and starting a bunch of identical containers with the `-d` flag as the only change, I have only seen quick responses from detached containers, but detached containers can also be slow to respond. I also think it's worth mentioning that 95%+ of the slow response times have been either 56s or 61s.

Trying to research this error gives me [plenty of responses about curl being slower when run inside a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656215/slowness-in-docker-container), but that is about all I can find.

If it matters, I'm working on a VM, have no access to the host, am always root, and am behind a network firewall and proxy, but I don't think this should matter when only dealing with localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm dumb.

[The getting started tutorial says that it can take a long time for http responses with this app](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app) because of an unmet dependency that they have you add further in the tutorial. Unfortunately, they say this on the next page, so if you're on part 2 and a beginner, it's not clear why this problem occurs until you give up and go on to part 3. They claim the response may take "up to 30 seconds"; mine is double that, but it's clear that this is the root cause.