# HTTP 403 response when accessing docker container on other host

Tags: docker

I am using Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72 on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511.

My goal is to get a docker container to publish on one of the host's ports and have the information be visible to another system in the same subnet. My docker image is the [friendlyhello image built in the getting started tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#dockerfile). I have [an image of it on docker hub](https://cloud.docker.com/swarm/jeremydr2/repository/docker/jeremydr2/get-started/general) which you can pull with the below command. It exposes port 80 within the file, and then I call the image with

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 jeremydr2/get-started:part2
```

I can get the correct response (basically "hello world") when I `curl localhost:8080` or `curl 10.x.x.x:8080` while on the host in which the container is running. When curling on another host, I get some html formatting and

```
 default "Access Denied" response (403)
```

[Note that a successful response can take over a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064576/docker-containers-http-response-slower-when-not-detached/47083382), but an unsuccessful response will still be immediate.

[From what](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/what-is-docker-networking) [I've read](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/776bgd/another_docker_noob_question_about_iptables/) [about this](http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101/), I shouldn't have to mess with iptables at all to get this to work, which is good, because I don't really understand networking very well. However, I think something is wrong, because `iptables -t nat -L | grep 8080` doesn't return anything, when I expect it to have a line about redirecting or allowing traffic to that port. I have disabled SELinux and firewalld, and installed iptables-services instead.

I can send traffic between the hosts with other commands like:

```
[root@host1 ~]# ncat -l 8001
[root@host2 ~]# echo "testing123" > /dev/tcp/<host1_ip_addr>/8001
```

so I feel confident it is not just a misconfigured network. FWIW, I've also tried the `docker run ...` command with `--network=host`, and this did not help, either. This has been 2 days of my life now. If anyone has advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: This is definitely, somehow, a misconfigured network. I redid it at home, and it "just worked" the way everyone says docker is supposed to. Any advice on how to go about figuring out what part of the network stuff is blocking docker would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the proxies I had set up to reach the internet. After unsetting all the proxy variables, I was able to curl from the other system to the host. I had been told that the `no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY` variables I had set up were sufficient to prevent this, but that was not the case.

Thanks for everyone who looked at this.

Comment: Thanks, checked http.nonProxyHosts and found that removed required host for testing purposes months ago and forgot ) You saved my time. Strange that for some ports I got also 503 error code.